# Problems with running insert query in php on MySQL server

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I am using the following code in the query, but it is not entering the data into the database. What is wrong with the format?

```
$query2="INSERT INTO user_details SET user_email='{$email}', user_fname='{$fname}', user_lname='{$lname}'";

$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
```

PS: I have properly defined $conn, the names of variables used are correct.

Comment: Have you any error? need more details

Comment: is it a duplicate on a unique key?

Comment: Add error handling and show the complete mysqli code, you might be sql injecting yourself.

Comment: What you have above is basically fine, presuming you filtered the user input. Your problem is rooted in the variables that are fed into the code above. `mysqli_error($conn)` is an informative friend.

Comment: Please don't insert values using string catenation. Use parameters to avoid SQL injections!

Answer (score 0):

The query started working when I deleted the table and created a new table with the same name. Seemed like some internal issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query2 = <<<SQL
 INSERT INTO 'user_details' ('user_email', 'user_fname', 'user_lname') 
 VALUES ('{$email}', '{$fname}','{$lname}');
SQL;
```

Comment: Please add what exactly you changed and how your answer works. This way other people can learn from your answer instead of simply copying code.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query2="INSERT INTO user_details (user_email,user_fname,user_lname) VALUES ('$email', '$fname','$lname')";
```